# Intersecting tables in R based on rownames string

Tags: r

I have 2 datasets: one set has [my actual data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnPCe.png), and the other one is a list of my [KOs of interest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qV5ZZ.png), and I'm trying to intersect the data to select only the KOs of interest.

As you can see, the row names also have the associated taxa. I've intersected these tables previously without the taxa data:

```
foi <- read.csv("krakened/biogeochemical.csv")
new <- intersect(rownames(kegg.f),foi$genefamily)
kegg.df.select <- kegg.f[new,]
```

but I'd really like to have the taxa in the row names. Is it possible to intersect the tables by only comparing the "KOxxxx" part of my rownames?

Answer (score 0):

We may use `trimws` to extract the substring, use `%in%` to find the matches in the genefamily column from 'foi' and subset using the logical vector

```
kegg.f[trimws(rownames(kegg.f), whitespace = "\\|.*") %in% foi$genefamily,]
```

It can also be done with `sub`

```
kegg.f[sub("^(K\\d+)\\|.*", "\\1", rownames(kegg.f)), %in% foi$genefamily,]
```